# Can't build with Leiningen

Tags: leiningen

I'm following the instructions on the Puppet Documentation for [running PuppetDb from source](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/latest/install_from_source.html), using the second option to use `lein deps`.

After running the command I get back:

```
Could not transfer artifact puppetlabs:puppetserver:pom:2.7.2 from/to releases (http://nexus.delivery.puppetlabs.net/content/repositories/releases/): nexus.delivery.puppetlabs.net: Name or service not known
Could not transfer artifact puppetlabs:puppetserver:pom:2.7.2 from/to releases (http://nexus.delivery.puppetlabs.net/content/repositories/releases/): nexus.delivery.puppetlabs.net
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

I don't have any problems with other package managers so I don't think it is a network issue. I've also tried both the master and stable branch from [github](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb). I have the same issue with both.

This is the first time I've used Leiningen so I'm wondering if it could be an issue with my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out despite [documentation saying](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/latest/install_from_source.html) this method would work for building PuppetDb from source it was not the case.

The puppetserver module referenced in the `project.clj` file was requiring access to a private repository owned by Puppet.

*[Received help](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PDB-3500) for this answer on Puppet's ticketing system.*